# No output from Julia via VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, executable-path

I've just upgraded from Julia-1.5 to Julia 1.6 and also installed the latest version of VScode on my Mac.
Till now I made only one setting:
"julia.executablePath": "/home/Applications/julia-1.6/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia"

Am not sure if this is correct/enough.

When I try to run a Julia code, then there appears no output.

Any idea what caused the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: How do you run Julia? Do you use the `julia-vscode` extension? Is it the "Run in REPL" command?

Comment: You might also double-check that the path you have specified is indeed the path to the Julia executable; /home/Applications/ is a fairly nonstandard location of Mac. If in doubt, paste the path into the terminal, and if correct Julia should run.

Comment: "I don't get the terminal working properly. It displays: "jaap:Codes Ospats-plus jjdegruijter$"

Comment: "I don't get the terminal working properly. It displays: "jaap:Codes Ospats-plus jjdegruijter$" – 
JdG

Comment: I use the julia-vscode extension, but I don't find the "Run in REPL" command

Comment: Meanwhile I managed to activate the julia executable outside vscode. That worked.